# Raspberry Pi control over SSH

Tags: python, raspbian, led, sirishortcuts

I have raspbery which is controlling LEDs in the room, I made a command which I can send over SSH (using iPhone shortcuts).
This code is running and animates LEDs, to turn all LEDs off I need to ctrl+c. Is there any way I can do this also over SSH, even I headed it has some problems I'd you reconnect to wifi after sending 1st command because it doesnt track already active commands?

I can share code also.

Kind Regards,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to kill the process, you can do that either with `killall nameoftheprocess`, or if you know the process id, using `kill pid`.

Here is the manpage for kill: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html

Assuming you start the command with a bash script, you should be able to get the pid using `$!`, you could then write that to a temporary file from which you can read for killing the process.

If you want more detail, it would be helpful if you shared your code.

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe it well. I dont need to kill the process just stop it. Stop execution of it in terminal,

Comment: @Directx995 That's exactly what killing means? Or do you mean something else by stopping? When you press Control + C, `kill -2 PID` is what is happening under the hood. I would again suggest you take a look at the man page for kill, and maybe this one as well, it contains a list of the signals you can send: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html

Comment: When I use command kill to target python3 as return in terminal I got "terminated", LEDs stops animating, but they remain on. I think I literally need to send command ^c somehow.

Comment: @Directx995 As I said, `kill -2 PID` is exactly what control + c does.

Comment: Sorry for a little late reply. @b3nj4m1n it's absolute perfect solution. I use the following code to call a small script on raspberry `sudo python3 /home/pi/rpi_ws281x/python/examples/allLeds_pleasentEffects.py -c ` when I want to close it I just use the code noted above `sudo pkill -2 python3 ` with a small adaptation to target process name and not ID since ID can change. Thanks a lot